# How do you send a join invitation to a friend in google play games 2021?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I'm looking for a way by which I can notify a friend player about my server/lobby somehow ,using the play games services . Things like steam invite you get in steamworks.

It appears the invite friends functionality has been removed with the multiplayer functionality. I am looking into a way to get the id or address of my server to other player directly using play games services as a invite.

Does this functionality still exist somewhere?

Comment: i'm not sure how this relates to programming or development, do you have any code to add to your question ? will this be achievable by code ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes, I'm basically asking about what API should I call to send a invite to an existing friend to join a game I'm playing

Answer (score 0):

found this on Google support page

Share an invite link Open Play Games . At the bottom, tap Profile and then Share .

also make sure your friend can recieve invitations

Open Play Games . Tap More and then Settings. Turn on "Let others find your profile using your email address". Tip: When this feature is turned off, your friends need to know your gamer name to send you an invite. Turn on Receive friend invites. If you turn this off, you can still send invitations to friends.

visit the link for more info https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9787064?hl=en

Comment: Unfortunately it's the "add freind" invitation and does not provide the other player with any info to join ongoing match

Comment: More of a comment rather than an answer